# ibtool failed with exit code 255 in Xcode 6-Beta

Tags: storyboard, interface-builder, swift, xcode6

I am constantly getting this error message while i am trying to run Application in device or Simulator.

Error :

```
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

I have cleaned project, Restart again, removed derived data as well still i am getting above error msg.

Any suggestions or hint will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue with xcode 7b4. Removing `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO"` from xib helped in my case

Answer (score 3):

In the Deployment Info, choose devices like "iPhone" instead of "Universal".

Answer (score 2):

Just uncheck use AutoLayout and build the project.

If you want to continue with AutoLayout then again check use autoLayout option.

Comment: Uncheck, build and run, then recheck, build and run and everything is back to normal. Thanks!